# Flutter Firestore: How to avoid conflicts in writing/updating a document that is available to multiple users at the same time?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am fairly new to Firestore, I am trying to figure out if there is a special technique to write or update a document or collection that is available to all users of the app.

E.g. in a e-commerce app, the current stock of goods collection, in case of two or more users making a simultaneous purchase (1 unit per user) of the same product, how to avoid conflict into updating the remaining quantity of that product? Or is it managed by the Firestore SDK automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two ways to achieve this:

#### If your field is a number and you don't use it in the operations

For example, if you want to reduce the stock, but you don't use the stock in your update operations, you can use [FieldValue.increment()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#static-increment). With this function you don't have to worry about multiple updates.

#### If you want to use the field in the operations.

For example, if before update the stock you want to verify if there is stock. With a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) you can get the stock, verify if there is no cero and the update it. If any other user updates the stock, the transaction function is rerun with the new stock value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) in Firestore to make sure that concurrent updates to a document are managed atomically.  The database does not do this for you - you must write the code for the transaction to make sure it's managed correctly.

For Flutter specifically, https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#transactions

Comment: Thank you so much for the second link, I looked at the first link before asking the question and didn't find code examples for Flutter so I thought it might not be it.